# PayPal submit button

Tags: javascript, php, css, security, paypal

Can someone tell me if there is any security issue in using a text button to submit a payment form in PP payments standard? i.e instead of using a button as in

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
```

I would like to be able to set the text from PHP and style in CSS using this:

```
<input type="submit" class="cart_button" value="'.$buttontext.'" title="Click here to view your order so far.">';
```

I've seen a number of threads about security issues on PP buttons, so if anyone can point me in the right direction here I'd appreciate it. 
Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0):

If not else, `value="'.$buttontext.'"` looks potentially vulnerable to cross-site scripting, unless `$buttontext` is a static or hard-coded value. Even if it is from your database, it would be better to just encode it.

Other than that it looks good to me, it's just a plain button.

Comment: Thanks for that input. Much appreciated. $buttontext is static, set within the same php procedure. I used a parameter so that the same string could be used in a help instruction also in the same procedure. Ray (ps I tried to upvote, but don't have the necesary 15 to do that!)